# Can I say "to range by alphabet"?

Tags: phrase-request

Can I say "to range by alphabet"? Or is it "to range in alphabetical order"? Suppose we have the words 'apricot', 'bush', and 'acrobat', and I place them in the following order: 'acrobat', 'apricot', 'bush'

Comment: If you place things in a specific order, you're ***arranging*** them. It's rare / poetic / archaic / invalid to use the verb ***range*** with this sense. If the verb ***arrange*** is to be used at all, AND we also want to include ***order***, we'd normally say something like *You must **arrange** these words **in alphabetical order*** (that's an *adjectival* usage). But most people would probably just say *You must **sort them alphabetically*** anyway (an *adverbial* usage).

Comment: Or you could use _put/list in alphabetical order_.

Comment: @fumblefingers what's wrong with "range"? One of its meanings is, according to Lexico, "Place or arrange in a row or rows or in a specified order or manner"

Comment: What's "wrong" with it is exactly what I said - this sense of ***to range*** is a dated / poetic / literary usage that would nearly always be expressed by ***to arrange*** today. The sequence ***words arranged alphabetically*** is as common as muck, but the sequence ***words ranged alphabetically*** is so rare [it doesn't even show on an NGram chart.](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=words+arranged+alphabetically%2Cwords+ranged+alphabetically&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwords%20arranged%20alphabetically%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: ..in fact, for good measure, here's [the one-and-only instance](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22words+ranged+alphabetically%22) of that sequence in Google Books. *That's* what's wrong with it! :)

Comment: @fumblefingers but Lexico didn't label it as dated, poetic of anything

Comment: So what? I know you don't have to believe *me*, since I'm just one person, and obviously my personal experience might be atypical. But do you not recognise and accept the implications of my NGram chart? Or (far more telling, imho) that *single* context-legible written instance in Google Books for what I'm pointing out is an unlikely / unusual usage, compared to probably *thousands* of written instances of ***words arranged alphabetically***. Also note that Google Books asked *Did you mean: "words arranged alphabetically"?* when I ran that first query.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Range" is used as a verb to describe things which can take many values, as a way of describing what values they can take.  For example, "The price of a litre of gasoline can range between $1.10 and $1.40 depending on the season", which means, "the price of gasoline will be some value between $1.10 and $1.40, and it will change depending on the season".

The word you are probably looking for is "arrange", commonly misheard as "range".  "To arrange in alphabetical order" is a proper construction.  However, when we (native English-speakers) speak of well-defined orderings such as alphabetic, we tend to prefer the word "sort"; "to sort in alphabetical order".

The difference between "arrange" and "sort" is that arranging does not necessarily follow any pattern at all, while sorting always follows a pattern where the previous item in the sequence is always either "greater" or "less" than the following item in some way.  For example, "sorting in alphabetical order" results that the previous word comes before the following word in alphabetical order.  "Sorting in numerical order", for example, could give you, say, "1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21", where the next number is larger than the previous.  And so on.